# passing mongo selector in an object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to supply the template with data which works when the selector is written `myCol.find({'p':'pen'})` but fails to return any documents when it is written like:

```js
Template.myTemp.helpers({
  docs: () => {
    let element = $('input:not(".inactive")');
    let query = {};
    let key = element.prop('name');
    query[key] = element.val();
    return myCol.find(query);  //<---- returns no documents ----
  }
});
```

I made sure the `query = {p: 'pin'}` in the browser console.
What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here, but is there a chance that mongo find `{p: 'pin'} != {'p':'pen'}`.

Comment: Well, your code looks good, there is not the issue with your code. Please add the following console.log before return in your helpers : console.log(myCol.find().fetch()) and console.log(myCol.find(query).fetch()) and share your output

Comment: @PankajJatav The issue was with the value being searched for. The fact that case sensitive is how mongodb 'finds' its document is what I did not pay attention to. Now it is fixed. Thx

Comment: Sounds Good ! . . .